# Selection Sort - Será que está correto?

Tags: java, algoritmo, classificação

Eu implementei uma lógica de selection sort e gostaria de perguntar se está correta. Pois ao finalizar o processo o resultado é o esperado, porém foi fazer uma prova real e achei diversos algoritmos mas nenhuma parecido com o meu.

Segue o código.

```
int vetor[] = {9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 6, 0};
int aux;

for(int i = 0; n = vetor.length; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++){
        if(vetor[j] > vetor[i]){
            aux = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = vetor[j];
            vetor[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}// fim do for

// aqui mando imprimir o vetor ordenado
for(int i = 0, n = vetor.length; i < n; i++){
    System.out.println("" + vetor[i]);
}
```

Comment: Você implementou o bubble sort e não o selection sort.

Comment: uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras: [algoritmos em animações](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms).

Comment: Obrigado caras! e Renan muito bom este exemplo visual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua lógica é do Bubble Sort, pois ele está trabalhando sempre com a próxima posição do vetor. O Selection Sort procura em todas as posições do vetor o valor mais baixo e faz a substituição no index ordenado.

**Selection Sort:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que ele sempre procura o valor mais baixo em todo o vetor, ao invés de trocar o próximo caso o valor já seja mais baixo.

[Exemplo de implementação](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/selection-sort/) (mesmo local onde retirei a imagem) os dois fazem a mesma coisa mas de formas diferentes

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, esse link deu pra compreender melhor perfeito =D